# record "new" has no field "i_produtos" postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION alter_fab() RETURNS TRIGGER 
    AS $alter_fab$

    BEGIN
        IF old.i_fabricantes != new.i_fabricantes and EXISTS(SELECT * FROM item as i
                                                                    INNER JOIN VENDA ON(venda.i_vendas = i.i_vendas)
                                                            WHERE i.i_produtos = NEW.i_produtos) then 
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Fabricante não pode ser alterado!';
        END IF;
    END;
$alter_fab$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA5ke.png)

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER alter_fab
    BEFORE UPDATE ON fabricante
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE alter_fab();
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

ERROR: record "new" has no field "i_produtos"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT old.i_fabricantes != new.i_fabricantes and EXISTS(SELECT * FROM item as i
INNER JOIN VENDA ON(venda.i_vendas = i.i_vendas)
WHERE i.i_produtos = NEW.i_produtos)"

Comment: What it is telling you is that whatever table this trigger is on does not have a `i_produtos` field or that the field name is either mixed or upper case and needs to be double quoted. To get a more definitive answer you will need to provide the trigger definition as well as the table definition. Add these as update to your question.

Comment: ok,,, is added.

Comment: Please do not use images for textual information. Copy and paste that information to your question. In any case the trigger is on the table `fabricante` and it does not have the `i_produtos` field so it will not be available in the `NEW` record. You are going to have to rethink your query to include values you have access to. I'm thinking `i.i_fabricantes = NEW.i_fabricantes`.